# How to set JSON Object Start with Result?.Net MySQL JSON Restful Webservice?

Tags: c#, mysql, json, web-services, rest

I Followed [this](http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/Services/WebServices-Page2.htm) to Create Restful Web Services which display JSON as OutPut from the MySQL Data base.

I Successfully Done it, But Here I Have nearly 100 Tables in Database with different name

for Getting Data I am Using this :

```
ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle =    WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getAllCustomers")]
List<wsCustomer> GetAllCustomers();
```

and this :

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
 public List<wsCustomer> GetAllCustomers()
{
NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
List<wsCustomer> results = new List<wsCustomer>();

foreach (Customer cust in dc.Customers)
{
    results.Add(new wsCustomer() { 
        CustomerID = cust.CustomerID,
        CompanyName = cust.CompanyName,
        City = cust.City
    });
}

return results;
}
```

I am Getting Data Output like this :

```
{
    "CustomerResult": [
        {
            "CustomerID ": "12124",
            "CompanyName ": "http://www.google.com",
            "City ": "xyz"
        }
    ]
}
```

But Here The Problem ist for Every Result i am getting Table Name Resulst like i have another table

```
{
    "UserResult": [
        {
            "UserID ": "12124",
            "CompanyName ": "http://www.google.com",
            "City ": "xyz"
        }
    ]
}
```

So Here Insted Of **CustomerResult** or **UserResult** I want it as **Result**

Is there any way to Display it as Result for all Tables.

Please Suggest Me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use map like structure to achieve this. I am not sure about .Net, but in java we do like this:

```
    Map<String,Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    resultMap.put("result","customerList");
    resultMap.put("status","success");
```

You can also use Map. As per my understanding, in your scenario it is returning table name as key because your method is returning the list directly. And to make it a json it require a key.

Comment: Thank you sir can you please try to tell me Regarding this C#(.net)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in JAVA Using Map,

```
public List<wsCustomer> GetAllCustomers()
            {
                NorthwindDataContext dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
                List<wsCustomer> results = new List<wsCustomer>();

                foreach (Customer cust in dc.Customers)
                {
                    results.Add(new wsCustomer() {
                        CustomerID = cust.CustomerID,
                        CompanyName = cust.CompanyName,
                        City = cust.City
                    });
                }
                Map<String,List<wsCustomer>> resultMap = new HashMap<String,List<wsCustomer>>();
                resultMap.put("result",results);
                return resultMap;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you sir can you please tell me Regarding this C#(.net)